# I am creating a Django API. For the purpose of authentication, I implemented, Djoser

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I send a POST request to create a user- successfully. I receive an email. Successfully send a POST request to activate it. I get an email: "Your account has been created and is ready to use!". When I send POST request /auth/jwt/create/ i get error: "POST /auth/jwt/create/ HTTP/1.1" 401 63
I can't solve it. I think is something in the JWT setting, but I can't found the right one.
This is a code from a tutorial I found on youtube.

> setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'o=*k95n2f6-6o8&fct=+(93_khqr18ax6zc1=gmv(dxe1js-pj'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #external
    'djoser',
    'backend',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'auth.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'auth.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'djoser_system',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    }
}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'stingertattoose@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'laejkajikkznpztm'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
}

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'backend.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'backend.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
    }
}

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'backend.UserAccount'
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)
        user.save()
        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

> serializers.py

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class UserCreateSerializer(UserCreateSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'name', 'password')
```

> urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
]

urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

> pip_list

```
 Package                       Version
    ----------------------------- ---------
    asgiref                       3.3.1
    astroid                       2.4.2
    certifi                       2020.11.8
    cffi                          1.14.3
    chardet                       3.0.4
    coreapi                       2.3.3
    coreschema                    0.0.4
    cryptography                  3.2.1
    defusedxml                    0.7.0rc1
    Django                        2.2
    django-templated-mail         1.1.1
    djangorestframework           3.12.2
    djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.6.0
    djoser                        2.1.0
    idna                          2.10
    isort                         5.6.4
    itypes                        1.2.0
    Jinja2                        2.11.2
    lazy-object-proxy             1.4.3
    MarkupSafe                    1.1.1
    mccabe                        0.6.1
    oauthlib                      3.1.0
    pip                           20.2.4
    psycopg2                      2.8.6
    psycopg2-binary               2.8.6
    pycparser                     2.20
    PyJWT                         1.7.1
    pylint                        2.6.0
    python3-openid                3.2.0
    pytz                          2020.4
    requests                      2.25.0
    requests-oauthlib             1.3.0
    setuptools                    50.3.2
    six                           1.15.0
    social-auth-app-django        4.0.0
    social-auth-core              3.3.3
    sqlparse                      0.4.1
    toml                          0.10.2
    uritemplate                   3.0.1
    urllib3                       1.26.2
    wheel                         0.35.1
    wrapt                         1.12.1
```

Answer (score 0):

djoser's contributer here. I believe the issue lives in your custom `UserAccountManager` implementation.

You pass a `password` argument into `create_user` method but you **do not** use it at all. I believe you should add a line marked with comment below:

```py
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("User must have an email address")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)
        user.set_password(password)  # <- add this to set the password
        user.save()
        return user
```

This should solve your issue with authentication endpoint.